Can OP accept the winning posts for Screenshots of the Week #121 and #123?
Timmy Jim posted Screenshot of the Week #121, and Robotnik posted Screenshot of the Week #123.
Could they both accept the winning answers, to say that they won and because all other (completed) Screenshots of the Week have accepted answers for the winner?

I'm not sure this really requires asking a question on Meta for.  You can instead just comment on the screenshot of the week post to ask the author to accept (I accepted the one for my post!)  I can also bother Robotnik later about it :)

@TimmyJim Oh yeah… that is an option isn’t it?

A few others are missing, btw

@pinckerman Oh, which ones?

16, 41-46, 49, 61, 69, 71, 75, 81, 96, 108...

Oh wow. That’s a lot.

There really isn't any purpose to accepting the winner on these posts anyway, other than the occasional badge you might earn on Meta

It makes it clear what answer wins, which might not be obvious if there is a tie or a second-place answer gets late votes.

@pppery Well, if two answers tie for first before the voting time is up, they both win. So I could see it being bad for that reason, actually. But this is rare.
